# Detect last boot is safe mode in Android

Tags: android

I have an application which already be granted as Device Admin Owner. I just want to know how do I check if last time device boot up is safe mode or not.

This is an instruction how user controls device:

1. User restart device from normal use to Safe mode.
2. User successfully entered Safe mode.
3. User restart device again and back to normal use.

I know that only System apps can run in Safe mode. So app should check in step 3. But i don't know how.

Any idea would be helpful. Thanks.